# Highlight text in Jquery Leaflet popup based on json value - use CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, leaflet

I have popups for my markers in leaflet that are populated with information from an ajax call.  What I would like to do is set up some rules for highlighting the data in the popup. But I'm not sure how. I want to do something similar to excels default conditional formatting. Maybe it should be done with CSS?

Similar to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RdGEy/

**EDIT:** It seems like this could be a good rabbit hole to follow: http://jsbin.com/zotome/edit?js,output

or this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmesE/1/

but I'm not having luck making it apply inside the popup. Also it looks to target the "p" which I don't want to do because of how ugly the formatting would get with all the extra space.

If markers[i]["Number"] is >= 150 Then Yellow background and Dark Yellow Text

If markers[i]["Number"] is >= 250 Then Red background and Dark Red Text

If (each treated separately) markers[i]["PropX"] >= .1 Then Yellow background and Dark Yellow Text

If (each treated separately) markers[i]["PropX"] >= .2 Then Red background and Dark Red Text

```
//pull data from json
jQuery.ajax({                              
url: myURL +  "map_data.php",
type: "JSON",
async: false,
success: function(data){
       markers = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       jQuery(markers).each(function( index, element ) {        
       });
} 
}); 

......

//generate markers and layers from data 
for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i ) {
    //define popup data
    var popup = '<br/><b>Sample Name:</b> '+ markers[i]["Sample_Number"] +
              '<br/><b>Location Description:</b> ' + markers[i]["Location_Description"] +
              '<br/><b>Date Taken:</b> ' + markers[i].Date +
              '<br/><b>Classification:</b> ' + markers[i].Classification +
              '<br/><b>Number:</b> ' + markers[i]["Number"] +
              '<br/><b>Proportion 1:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop1"] +
              '<br/><b>Proportion 2:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop2"] +
              '<br/><b>Proportion 3:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop3"] +
              '<br/><button onclick="window.location=`http://...data.php?sample_name='+ markers[i]["File_Name"] +'`" download="'+markers[i]["File_Name"]+' data.csv">Download Data</button>'    

    //define markers    
    var m = L.marker( [markers[i].Latitude, markers[i].Longitude], {icon: icons[markers[i].Classification]})
                  .bindPopup( popup );

    var data = {};            
    var name =  markers[i]["File_Name"];
    var latlng = L.latLng([markers[i].Latitude, markers[i].Longitude]);
    data.name = name;
    data.latlng = latlng;
    bulk_list.push(data);   


    //add data to layer groups
    category = markers[i].Classification;
    // Initialize the category array if not already set.
    if (typeof categories[category] === "undefined") {
    categories[category] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup,m).addTo(map);
    layersControl.addOverlay(categories[category], category);
    }
    //add layers to map
    categories[category].addLayer(m);
}
```

The popups will look like this (with highlighting rules applied):

```
Sample Name: S16
Location Description:place
Date Taken:
Classification: Unknown
Number: 149
Proportion 1: 0.11 #This line of text would be dark yellow with a yellow background
Proportion 2: 0.03
Proportion 3: 0.03

Sample Name: S17
Location Description:place
Date Taken:
Classification: Unknown
Number: 150 #This line of text would be dark yellow with a yellow background
Proportion 1: 0.11 #This line of text would be dark yellow with a yellow background
Proportion 2: 0.23 #This line of text would be dark red with a red background
Proportion 3: 0.03

Sample Name: S18
Location Description:place
Date Taken:
Classification: Unknown
Number: 255 #This line of text would be dark red with a red background
Proportion 1: 0.01
Proportion 2: 0.23 #This line of text would be dark red with a red background
Proportion 3: 0.13 #This line of text would be dark yellow with a yellow background
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a css class directly in the popup.

```
    var numberclass = "";
    if(markers[i]["Number"] >= 250){
        numberclass = "redhighlight";
    }else if(markers[i]["Number"] >= 150){
        numberclass = "yellowhighlight";
    }

     var popup = '<br/><b>Sample Name:</b> '+ markers[i]["Sample_Number"] +
              '<br/><b>Location Description:</b> ' + markers[i]["Location_Description"] +
              '<br/><b>Date Taken:</b> ' + markers[i].Date +
              '<br/><b>Classification:</b> ' + markers[i].Classification +
              '<br/><span class="'+numberclass+'"><b>Number:</b> ' + markers[i]["Number"] +'</span>'+
              '<br/><span class="'+getPropColor(markers[i]["Prop1"])+'"><b>Proportion 1:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop1"] +'</span>'+
              '<br/><span class="'+getPropColor(markers[i]["Prop2"])+'"><b>Proportion 2:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop2"] +'</span>'+
              '<br/><span class="'+getPropColor(markers[i]["Prop3"])+'"><b>Proportion 3:</b> ' + markers[i]["Prop3"]+'</span>';

function getPropColor(value){
    if(value >= 0.2){
        return "yellowhighlight";
  }else if(value >= 0.1){
        return "redhighlight";
  }else{
    return "";
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.redhighlight{
  background: red;
  color: darkred;
}

.yellowhighlight{
  background: yellow;
  color: orange;
}
```

I have created a example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/s9d4na2t/

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, I was attempting to do something like that, but outside of the loop that creates the markers.  Doh!